# nHibernate Table per Concrete Wrong Class Exception

Tags: xml, nhibernate, exception, mapping

I am having some problems with creating the xml mapping file for the following class hierarchy using Table per concrete way in nHibernate. I keep on getting "Wrong Class Exception" error. Can anyone help pointing me in the right direction?

This is the definition of my abstract/parent class:

```
public abstract partial class AlertSpecification
{
    private long _alertSpecificationId;
    private string _specificationName;
    private bool _active;
    private int _createdBy;
    private DateTime _createdOn;

    public virtual long AlertSpecificationId
    {
        get { return _alertSpecificationId; }
        set { _alertSpecificationId = value; }
    }

    public virtual string SpecificationName
    {
        get { return _specificationName; }
        set { _specificationName = value; }
    }

    public virtual bool Active
    {
        get { return _active; }
        set { _active = value; }
    }

    public virtual int CreatedBy
    {
        get { return _createdBy; }
        set { _createdBy = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get { return _createdOn; }
        set { _createdOn = value; }
    }
}
```

This is the definition of my 1st child class:

```
public partial class ComponentSpecification : AlertSpecification
{
    private string _vehicleType;

    public virtual string VehicleType
    {
        get { return _vehicleType; }
        set { _vehicleType = value; }
    }          
}
```

This is the definition of my 2nd child class:

```
public partial class ColdVehicleSpecification : AlertSpecification
{
    private double _sigmaThreshold;

    public virtual double SigmaThreshold
    {
        get { return _sigmaThreshold; }
        set { _sigmaThreshold = value; }
    }        
}
```

This is the definition of my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"        

     namespace="IS.QueryPerformanceTest.Model" assembly="IS.QueryPerformanceTest.Model" >
        <class name="AlertSpecification" abstract="true">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>    
       <id name="AlertSpecificationId" type="Int64">      
           <generator class="hilo"/>
       </id>
    <property name="SpecificationName" column="Name" />
    <property name="Active" />
    <property name="CreatedBy" />
    <property name="CreatedOn" />  
    <union-subclass name="ColdVehicleSpecification"   table="AlertSpecificationColdVehicle">
        <property name="SigmaThreshold" column="CVSigmaThreshold" />      
    </union-subclass>   
    <union-subclass name="ComponentSpecification" table="AlertSpecificationComponent">
        <property name="VehicleType" column="VehicleType" />      
    </union-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In my controller, I use the following code to retrieve the data back:

```
var repo = new NHComponentSpecificationRepository(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>

());

var cvRepo = new 

NHColdVehicleSpecificationRepository(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>());

var allComponentSpecs = repo.FindAll();
var allColdVehicleSpecs = cvRepo.FindAll();
```

This is the error that I am getting:
Object with id: 1 was not of the specified subclass: IS.QueryPerformanceTest.Model.ColdVehicleSpecification (loading object was of wrong class [IS.QueryPerformanceTest.Model.ComponentSpecification])

Note that the first call to repo.FindAll() returns fine with the correct type. However the second call was failing. For some reasons, It always try to load ComponentSpecification even though I have specified in the code to load ColdVehicleSpecification.

This is the implementation of FindAll in NHColdVehicleSpecificationRepository:

```
public IList<ColdVehicleSpecification> FindAll()
{
    var result = _session.Query<ColdVehicleSpecification>().ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Does anyone have any clue what is wrong here?

Please let me know if you need further information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is one ID generator for the hierarchy. When you load the object with ID 1, NH finds the type in question. If you try to load it as a different type, it crashes.

```
ComponentSpecification cs = new ComponentSpecification ();
session.Store(cs);
var csId = cs.Id;

// later on,
// crashes with a cast exception
var cvs = session.Get<ColdVehicleSpecification>(csId);
```

If this is not the problem, you need to provide some code.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I have added some more code. Hope that helps.